# What is Tell in Construct?

Tags: python, construct

I'm porting some binary parsing Python code to C# and I encountered the Construct field type `Tell` which I cannot find described in Construct's documentation.

Example code:

```
objects = "objects"/Struct(
    "type"/Byte,
    "position"/Byte,
    attributes,
    "end_of_attr"/Tell, # this
    "next_object"/Byte
)
```

What is it?
What does it represent?
How does it behave when parsing a binary file?

Comment: Could it be this? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: It's documented:

https://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/streaming.html#construct.Tell